# How can I use observedAttributes to an anonymous class / function?

Tags: javascript, web-component

I want to register a custom element with an anonymous class / function. But I wonder how to use the `observedAttributes` to the object?

**Class Version. How it works**

```js
<my-el name="abc"></my-el>
class MyEl extends HTMLElement {...}
MyEl.observedAttributes = ["name"];
```

**Version anonymous class/ function. How it does not work**

```js
window.customElements.define("my-el", class extends HTMLElement {...});

// how i can bind now?
MyEl.observedAttributes() // throws an error: ReferenceError: MyEl is not defined
```

Comment: `window.customElements.define("my-el", class extends HTMLElement {...}` <= That missing `)` is a typo, correct?

Comment: @zer00ne yes it is only a typo. correct. thanks for hinting me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) on your class expression like so, which is supported in ES2015 and above:

```js
window.customElements.define("my-el", class extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["name"];
  }
});
```

Otherwise, if you can support ES2022 and above, you can create a [public static field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) (rather than a getter):

```js
window.customElements.define("my-el", class extends HTMLElement {
  static observedAttributes = ["name"];
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! I will check it out and give you a feedback soon!